# Execute script after docker build

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I am building a **RabbitMQ** broker with **docker** and used the official docker image (rabbitmq:3) in my Dockerfile.

I need to launch a script (setup.sh) to setup the users and admins for the broker.

When I execute the Dockerfile,

```
FROM rabbitmq:3
COPY provision /usr/src/provision
WORKDIR /usr/src/provision
EXPOSE 15672
EXPOSE 5672
EXPOSE 4369
RUN ./setup.sh
```

I get :

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@db52ce2c88d9'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@db52ce2c88d9
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@db52ce2c88d9]

rabbit@db52ce2c88d9:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on db52ce2c88d9
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on db52ce2c88d9
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-4810-rabbit@db52ce2c88d9'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: tql1bCPiwbtLGtuDAB3tOQ==
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Removing intermediate container db52ce2c88d9
 ---> 79851f024ae3
Successfully built 79851f024ae3
Successfully tagged rmq_v0:latest
```

How can I execute the file AFTER removing the intermediate container, but also not an `docker exec` command, it must be automatised.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send commands to the service without initiating it before so. I suggest not to add data to the image itself, but after it has been initiated. Depending where those images are going to be executed (plain Docker, Docker Swarm, Kubernetes, etc), you can add the initial data during a warming process (previous to init). Depending on the time taken by this action and the scaling needs (and the variability of this data and the infra where all this is going to be executed), some performance improvements can be made to this step, for example, cloning a volume with the binary data already applied before initiating a new instance.

Comment: @Camille SAURY If this answer didn't helped, please, comment why.